# How to select item by typing a keyboard letter key in WPF combobox?

Tags: wpf, select, combobox, hotkeys

I have a WPF `ComboBox` and I want to go to items that start with (for example) "e" in the `ComboBox` when I type that letter. How?

My XAML code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}" SelectedValuePath="Id"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisplayName}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRole}"
          Width="150"/>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm guessing you have an `ItemTemplate` that looks a little like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Foo}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Bar}" />
</StackPanel>
```

If you want to search on Foo, then try...

```
<ComboBox IsEditable = "True" TextSearch.TextPath = "Foo" />
```

By default a `ComboBox` has a kind of autocomplete that finds matches based on first letter - assuming your source is sorted alphabetically this will shift the selected item to the section that (for example) starts with "e".

Catching `KeyDown` to force the dropdown to open might be useful if you expect several entries starting with the same letter.

Comment: Should be :/ Make sure that you at least have the MyCombo.IsDropDownOpen = True fired when you catch a keypress. Again, this isn't useful if you're bound collection isnt alphabetically sorted (since it will just jump to the first word of a given letter it finds, rather than filter them). The code I provided should get you started for a filtering autocompletion, however.

Comment: yes I can edit the combo but it is not finding the data I search for. Just edit is enable. ??

Comment: And I just want to jump, it is enough for me.

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDisplayName">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: Is name a string? Is there any reason you have it in a contentPresenter and not a textblock or something?

Comment: Yes, I think it is about dataTemplate. I will look for it. thanks.

Comment: In fact, There is no need to add IsEditable, It is enough to add as below..
IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"

Comment: IsTextSearchEnabled by itslef will only work if your items are strings otherwise if they are custom CLR objects it will call ToString() resulting in something like "MyObject" which is probably not what you want. Use IsEditbale only if you want it to be editable! Otherwise override ToString() or Handel the KeyDown event and do it procedurally

Answer (score 15):

Assuming your items are sorted alphabetically, simply setting `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"` should jump to the items starting with the letter (or letters) you type into the `ComboBox`.

Here is an example of one of my `ComboBox`es, I have simplified the bindings as it's clearly not the important part here...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description"
          SelectedValuePath="Code"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
```

This works perfectly for selecting a value from the list, however, the search value you type will not display in the TextBox part of the control as I have `IsEditable` set to false.

If anyone would like to explain why this has been voted down it would be appreciated, I don't see any problem with the answer I've provided and don't see why I deserve to lose reputation when I'm only trying to help (and have provided a reasonable answer!)

Comment: Don't you want IsEditable = true, rather than TextSearchEnabled?

Comment: I can't see TextSearchEnabled?

Comment: It works perfectly on my ComboBoxes, it might be because I have IsEditable set to false, I don't want to be able to enter a value that isn't already in the list.  Focusing on the control and hitting for example, "M" takes me to the first entry starting with "M".  Don't know why yours isn't working, a down vote seems a little harsh though!

Comment: +1 - this shouldn't of been downvoted, especially not twice! Works just as well, especially since now we know the problem is the Template.

Comment: In fact, There is no need to add IsEditable, It is enough to add as below.. IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"

Comment: IsTextSearchEnabled calls ToString() on the objects in the Items - if you have a custom object, i.e. not a string, it will not appear to work as will be calling on ToString() which will give something like "MyObject" unless you override the ToString() in your custom object to output say the Code property...

Comment: I suspect the down vote is more due to the way you are misusing WPF and using the very "winforms" way of doing it, ie DisplayMemberPath instead of using a DataTemplate.

Comment: Using the DisplayMemberPath is a perfectly valid and simple way of doing this, using DataTemplates for everything is just overkill in my opinion.  Also, it might be considered the "WinForms" way of doing things, but I'd never even worked with WinForms before doing WPF (unfortunately I'm stuck doing WinForms now though!)

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was add the following:

```
TextSearch.TextPath="<what ever you bound to goes here> ie:State or name "
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this might help someone.
If you are using binding, which you should be, along with ItemSource and SelectedItem, then just adding TextSearch.TextPath="your bound display property" as stated by @mwolff works fine.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentTypes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEquipmentType,Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        SelectedValuePath="Equipment_Type_ID" 
TextSearch.TextPath="Equipment_Type_Code" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Popup">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="155"/>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Equipment_Type_Code}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```