# WPF Combobox select focused item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, focus

I'm using this method to focus on specific combo box item.

```
/// <summary>Combo box focus index.</summary>
private int cbfi = -1;
/// <summary>Focus specified list item based on char match to language name.</summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void onLangComboInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    var ch = e.Text;
    var it = cb.findNext<StackPanel, UIElement>(
        //...
    );
    if (it == null) return;
    it.Focusable = true;
    it.Focus();
    Keyboard.Focus(it);
}
```

The method works in sense that it focuses correctly item from the list, and the list is scrolled fine but I have a problem when applying focused item as `ComboBox SelectedItem` when I Hit Enter - some other item than the focused one is selected and I can't figure out why. It looks like keyboard focus is not set correctly.

**Update**

Basically I have regular `System.Windows.Controls.Combobox` with list of about 300 custom view items.
I want the basic functionality to jump to item which starts with corresponding character in expanded list when I hit the character on keyboard (But I don't want automatic selection, just focus and scroll to that element).

And again. I have CUSTOM item view which I add to `ListView` through `Items.Add(mycustomUIElement)` and the `ListView` instance is set as `DataContext` of the `ComboBox`. Each view item have it's own `DataContext` assigned to particular data item. And the data item contains nested string property that is compared with input character. Also I have alternative string if the primary on is not available so I can't really use build in functionality like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206069/how-to-select-item-by-typing-a-keyboard-letter-key-in-wpf-combobox).

The item searching and scrolling is working fine but but keyboard focusing seem to not always work. Like when I hit enter, wrong item is selected, or when use arrow keys, next item is not the neighbor of the target items.

Comment: for that kind of job I'd advise you to use binding, have you an idea already of what it is?

Comment: I do but the actual string that where i'm actually matching searching input character is nested deep inside data object, and I don't know how I could use binding to achieve my goal.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I wrote some more details

Comment: You can try selecting the item with enter in code. E.g. listen to "Enter" keydown, when it happens, set "SelectedItem" to the one which is highlighted. Maybe using a "IsHighlighted" property (if it exists) or using some other way that will tell you which item is supposed to be selected. Can't write code atm, so just throwing ideas

Comment: I probably could to this but it's not easy to tell how exactly I should handle the keyboard events to not block something else - I would need this only when CB is expanded and how know for what other things the Enter would be used on the control so this makes things complicated and I would rather not try to touch that for now as this seem to be minor issue for me and I could introduce a serious one with keyboard events...

Comment: and still, I think the real question would be why Keyboard focus in not working.